# Is it possible to include an image in a HTML email in Laravel

Tags: php, html, email, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm currently trying to send an HTML email via Laravel's `Mail::send()`. The view in which I'm using is a Blade template, but I'm not quite sure on how I would go about including an image in the body of the email.

In my template, I have

```
<h4>You have successfully updated your Session!</h4>

@if ( $old_date != $date)
    <p>You have changed from {{ $old_date }} to {{ $date }}</p>
@endif

<p>If you have any questions or concerns, please contact the Office of Admissions</p>

{{ HTML::image('/images/full-logo.png', 'logo') }}
```

However, my email comes out with just a broken link icon in the body of the email. Is it possible to pass an image as a parameter to the view? In my Controller which sends the email, I have

```
$data = array (
                        'first_name'    => $student->first_name,
                        'last_name'     => $student->last_name,
                        'date'          => $day,
                        'old_date'      => $old_day,
                );


Mail::send ( '/emails/create_student', $data, function ($message) {
    ...
} );
```

So I'm not sure if it might be possible to include an image via the `$data` array.

Comment: Yes it is possible , check for the image path if it is getting resolved.

Comment: The e-mail isn't on your website. You need to use the full URL to the image on your website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HTML::image()` generates absolute path to image, like this:

```
http://yoursite.dev/image.png
```

which works perfectly in your local environment.

Mail client, as Gmail, will override image path with something like this:

```
http://images.gmail.com/?src=http://yoursite.dev/image.png
```

Obviosly 3rd party service can't access your local domain and so you see broken image.

As a solution, you can upload images to 3rd party service like Amazon AWS and pass link to uploaded image to email template.

Answer (score 9):

This one worked for me:
 The image is declared in the email view

```
<img src="{{ $message->embed(public_path() . '/resources/icon/icon.png') }}" alt="" />
```

from [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail)
"A $message variable is always passed to e-mail views, and allows the inline embedding of attachments."